# Bootstrap table - remove ordering on the first load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is it possible to disable default table ordering on the **first load of page**? So default my table shouldn't order records, but when I click the header of table - it should order then.
I'm using this layout: https://wrappixel.com/demos/free-admin-templates/maruti-admin/tables.html

and I tried in these ways:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable({
        "order": []
    });
});
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": []
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work fine.

Comment: Error message is: ataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Answer (score 1):

I think your table id is incorrect. I disabled order option in my table like code below:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "order": []
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/nxfd7rkv/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running `$('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable(***)` more than one time.

It's probably because the `datatable()` method is once executing one the html you are using and once via the script that you wrote.